# Обновление данных после ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

есть ajax запрос, который открывает php файл, где происходят действия, и после их выполнения на success нужно изменить значения некоторого input, но проблема в том, что в php несколько исходов и они, можно сказать, противоположны по исходу (один из них заменяет $_SESSION['b'], другой исход и $_SESSION['b'], и $_SESSION['a']). Можно ли как то использовать эти значения в success и как это сделать? Может написать в конце php echo и эти переменные и в

```
success : function (data) { 
                            var a = "<?php $_SESSION['b'] или echo $_SESSION['b'] ?>"; вот тут нужно использовать одну из данных
                                    },
```

Подскажите , пожалуйста, как передать значения из php  в ajax и использовать их.
Видел, что еще писали protect($_GET...), но не особо понял как это использовать и можно ли вообще.

Comment: Самый логичный путь в данном случае - включить эти данные в объект `data`.

Comment: Можно ли чуть-чуть по-подробней? Где `data` должен быть создан и как записать в него эти переменные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш php скрипт должен вернуть результат. Вам решать в каком он будет формате, но удобней пользоваться JSON. Используйте [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) для формирования ответа.
Если для отправки запроса вы используете [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) то необходимо указать dataType: 'json' Таким образом, вы получите в data нужные данные

JavaScript

```
$.ajax('http://url-to-your-script', {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }
})
```

PHP

```
<?php
  $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: хорошо, сейчас посмотрю. А если я в ajax еще оптравляю данные методом POST, то , как мне быть? могу ли я также передать значение json и получить их в php. Простите за глупые вопросы, но json ни разу не использовал

Comment: Можете. В ссылке по jQuery, что есть в ответе вы можете прочитать как отправить запрос ( method: 'POST' ) А для PHP есть функция json-decode